# Function in C with unknown input data type

Tags: c, string, pointers, type-conversion, void

I'm trying to write a simple function that will convert a number to a string with respect to a given format, something like this:

```
char * write_number(const char *format, void *number) {
    char mystring[50];
    sprintf(mystring, format, number);
    return mystring;
}
```

The only problem is that this works with the integer data type, but not with the float/double data type. Is there any way to make this work regardless of the data type.

Thanks!

Addition to the original question:

Thank you for your suggestions. I didn't manage to make it work, here is the complete example of what am I trying to get.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void write_number(const char *format, void *number) {
    char mystring[50];
    sprintf(mystring, format, *number);
    printf("%s\n", mystring);
}

int main(void) {
    int a = 10;
    float b = 20;
    double c = 40;

    write_number("int: %03d", &a);
    write_number("float: %6.2f", &b);
    write_number("double: %6.2f", &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, and that function is broken anyway: It returns the address of a local variable.

Comment: Yes, it is true, the function is broken due to the wrong return statement. But why does this work with integer data type?

Comment: add this: printf("void*=%d, int=%d, float=%d, double=%d", sizeof(void *), sizeof(int), sizeof(float), sizeof(double));   my guess, is that you'll get 4, 4, 8, 8  (assuming float doesn't work), or if float works, you'll get 4, 4, 4, 8.

Answer (score 0):

The format string for `sprintf` specifies the data type, eg `"%i"` prints and integer and `"%f"` prints a float - hence you would need to change the format string depending on the data type.

Note also that the function is not guarnetied to work for ints either, since its returning a pointer to a local variable `mystring`, this will go out of scope when the function returns and can be overwritten at any time by another value, so then the returned pointer will be pointing to some random value rather than the string.

Answer (score 0):

For the calling code to use the address of the local variable `mystring[]` is *undefined behavior*.

> "why does this work with integer data type?"

*Undefined behavior* does not mean code "won't work".  It does does not mean if it works today (with integer) , it will work tomorrow.   It means the behavior is **not defined**.

Answer (score -1):

`sprintf` already takes care of the types of its arguments; you just need to make sure that the format string you pass to it matches it arguments. For example, `"%f", 3.125f` to format a float, `"%d", 12` to format a signed integer, `"%e", 3.125` to format a double precision float. Try reading [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Your function won't work anyway, though, as compilation errors will tell you. `mystring` is declared as a local variable on the stack, so it will cease to exist when your function returns.

Also, you are passing the *address* of `number` to `sprintf` instead of its *value*. To pass the value, you need to dereference it like this: `sprintf(mystring, format, *number);`

You function may work with an integer type because pointers are integral, so if you called `write_number("%d\n", 55)`, you would be passing a pointer to memory address 55, which `sprintf` would interpret as an integer because of the `%d`. If your `int`s and `void *`s weren't the same size this wouldn't work.

To actually pass a pointer instead of an int casted to a pointer do something like this:

```
char *str;
float num = 8.375f;
str = write_number("%f", &num);
```

Comment: So if I call it as write_number("%f", 1.0f), this won't work? (I know it wont, I already tried that). Is there any way to make it work, since sprintf converts the data type with respect to the given format? Disregard the return statement, I know it is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @Marko Well, it likely will work with a cast because floats are usually the same size as ints and pointers. But really you need to declare the float elsewhere and pass a pointer to it.

Comment: I'm trying to write a function for a dsPIC microcontroller, so int and float data types are not of the same size. Ok, it seems that this can't work in general. I hoped that sprintf function will convert the data type itself with respect to the given format.

Comment: I also tried with dereferencing, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: `dereference it like this: sprintf(mystring, format, *number);` That won't even compile since `void` pointers cannot be dereferenced, in this case  `void *number`.

Comment: `pointers are integral` and `floats are usually the same size as ints and pointers` - first one is just wrong, second one is mostly wrong except in some particular cases.